# Logging in to website with C# with MD5 password encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, authentication, httpwebrequest, md5

I've searched this site and found how to programmatically log in to a website in C#. However, this specific site encrypts the password somehow before sending the form.

I snooped on several POSTs using Live HTTP Headers for Firefox and found:

```
Account=[REDACTED]&pw=a0c41f57ef14e43642269bb1e452ae40
Account=[REDACTED]&pw=17fd04959cdf6f44b799221fb9a2e0e3
```

The password that is sent changes every time.

[As I press login, I can see the password change in the form.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6j4l.gif)

I looked at the page source and it might use "MD5 encryption", however I don't know how I would call the function that encrypts it, and I don't know why it changes every time after researching MD5.

Here's the function:

```
function doLogin(form)
{
   var originalpw = form.pw.value;
   var b64pw = b64_md5(originalpw);
   var hmac_md5pw = hex_hmac_md5(pskey, b64pw)
   form.pw.value = hmac_md5pw;
   form.dbpw.value = hex_hmac_md5(pskey, originalpw.toLowerCase())
   if (form.ldappassword!=null) {
       // LDAP is enabled, so send the clear-text password
       // Customers should have SSL enabled if they are using LDAP
       form.ldappassword.value = originalpw; // Send the unmangled password
   }

return true;
}
```

EDIT:

Alright, now I'm running the javascript using Noesis.Javascript. It works perfectly, but one last thing is the "pskey" variable. It changes every time you load the login page, and I found where it is so I can Regex it from the page source.

HOWEVER:

How will the page know that the webclient that downloaded the html code for the pskey is the same one that sends the POST to login and also GETs the logged in page?

I have these requests:

- GET login page for pskey
- POST login
- GET logged in page

How can I use the same WebClient for each?

Comment: MD5 is not encryption, its (an outdated) hasher

Comment: My question still stands, @Plutonix

Comment: You have the code to emulate right there. What's the question?

Comment: I'm writing it in C#, not javascript @bartonjs

Comment: Are you hoping for someone to write the C# code for you? What do you actually want to know? You have answered your own question already.  You literally posted the code.

Comment: @LukePark I guess what I was asking is how I can run javascript in C#, but I figured that out by now.

Comment: juat curioous , but what website is this??

Comment: @MukundB prefer not to state

Comment: If I would guess, it's that `pskey` is always different when you open the login page, because it's probably something like an CSRF token. This code suggests that the page you're trying to log in to stores the passwords either in plain text or as a single MD5 hash. Both are terrible choices. This is how you do it properly: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/45523

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript can be run in C# by using [Javascript.Net](https://github.com/JavascriptNet/Javascript.Net).

```
using Noesis.Javascript;

//...

string runJavascript(string str){
    using (JavascriptContext context = new JavascriptContext())
    {
        //Set external variables:
        context.SetParameter("var", str);
        context.Run("function jsFunc(s) { //encode in here } str2 = jsFunc(var)");
        Console.WriteLine(context.GetParameter("str2"));
        return context.GetParameter("str2").ToString();
    }
}
```